# Typescript requires different return type depending on scenario

Tags: typescript, axios

Hi I am new to typescript and need some understanding on this particular stuff.

I am returning an axios api response with the following format:

```
async function callApi(value:string):Promise<string>{
  return await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value})
}
```

This works. But if I want to refactor it to become

```
async function callApi(value:string):Promise<string>{
  const result = await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value})
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

It will throw TS lint error saying Type 'AxiosResponse' is missing the following properties from `Type 'AxiosResponse<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'`

And I tried

```
async function callApi(value:string):Promise<AxiosResponse<string>>{
  const result = await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value})
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

but it didnt work.
Any idea why the same return result requires different typings? How should I make it work?

Comment: in the second example you have marked return type as `:Promise<string>`,  but because you are awaiting `await axios....` inside the function, it'll get resolved to `string` type instead of a `Promise<string>`. Similar thing is happening with your third example as well. Simply do `return axios...` to fix the problem. Also to do `await` inside a function, the function itself should be asynchronous, like so `async function callApi(......`

Comment: @boop_the_snoot hi sorry I missed out the async when i posted this question.I havejust edited. It should have it. I dont quite get you what you mean by `return axios...` , how do I do it? Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bissecting your example here:

```
// Function is ALWAYS expected to return Promise<string>
async function callApi(value:string): Promise<string> {   
  const result = await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value} )
  // Because you have awaited here ^^^, its converted to `AxiosResponse<string>` instead of `Promise<string>`
  return result 
  // Thus, ^^^ `result` is of type 'AxiosResponse<string>', which contradicts function's expected return type, ie Promise<string>
}
```

Your requirement can be written in multiple ways, like so:

Example 1:

```
function callApi(value:string): Promise<AxiosResponse<string>> {
  return axios.post('/api/something', { key: value});
}
```

Example 2:

```
async function callApi(value:string): AxiosResponse<string> {  
  return await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value} );
}
```

Example 3:

```
async function callApi(value:string): AxiosResponse<string> {  
  const result = await axios.post('/api/something', { key: value} );
  return result;
}
```

Example 4:

```
async function callApi(value:string): string {  
  const result = await axios
                       .post('/api/something', { key: value} )
                       .then(r => r.json()); // This will auto-convert to expected return type
  return result; // its type is `string`, instead of `AxiosResponse<string>`
}
```

Usage of all the examples given above:

```
callApi('test').then(...);
// OR
const resp = await callApi('test'); // to use like this, calling function should also be marked `async`
```